# Calculating profit from price and cost

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, stock-market, price, equilibrium-price

For a given item, if we know that the equilibrium price is 400 and the cost of manufacturing quantity $x$ of the item is $2x^3+900$, then how can I find the profit?

My initial thoughts are that this is insufficient information to work out profit, but I am curious to know whether or not there is a way.

Comment: You're right. There is insufficient information to answer this question. However, if we know that this firm is a price taker and choose quantity such that it maximises its profit then we can use the information to solve the problem and determine the optimal profit.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I do that for this particular problem? @Amit

Comment: Just try and solve this maximisation problem: $\max_{x\geq 0} \ 400x - 2x^3 - 900$. Update your answer with your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The profit of the firm by definition is:

$$\Pi= TR-TC$$

Where $\Pi$ is profit, $TR$ total revenue and $TC$ total cost. By definition total revenue is price times quantity $TR=P \cdot Q$ (in your case quantity is $x$). Price could also be function of quantity, the problem does not mention whether firm is price taker or not. However, reading between the lines it looks like firm is assumed to be price taker otherwise it would be weird not to provide demand or inverse demand function (unless this is supposed to be nasty trick question I would say it’s fair to assume firm is price taker).

Hence plugging in your parameters we have:

$$\Pi = 400x - 2x^2 -900$$

Taking derivative the above wrt $x$ and equating it to 0 we get conditions for profit maximization:

$$400-4x=0 \implies 100=x^*$$

With $x=100$ the profit is:

$$\Pi = 400 \cdot 100 - 2 \cdot 100^2 -900=19100$$

The caveat is that the above would hold only for firm that is price taker (perfect competition). If it would be monopoly/monopolistically competitive firm the equilibrium price would not stay 400 when firm would change output (except in some corner cases like monopoly with perfectly elastic demand).  But I think perfect competition is unstated assumption here.